# Firebird synchronization on 2 computers running a Delphi App

Tags: delphi, firebird

I've migrated and old software (that runs on 2 pcs) from BDE to Firebird.

**Problem**: when insert/update on one pc, the other doesn't "see" DB updates until I close and reopen the software.
All new/updated records are regulary saved on DB file (checked with Flamerobin) but they aren't shown on the PC that hasn't made the insert/update.
It seems like software needs to refresh DB data after the other one has inserted something (I thought this was handled directly by FB server)

Please let me know what I've missed :(

**Some Infos:**
Software connect to DB via `IBDatabase` and `IBTransaction`.
After every Post or Update a call to `IBTransaction.CommitRetaining` is made.
Transaction Isolation Level is Read Commited
FB Server is on PC1 in SuperServer Mode
PC1 DB connection is : `IBDatabase.Name := mydb`
PC2 DB connection is : `IBDatabase.Name := PC1:mydb`
In aliases.conf is declared : mydb = C:\USERS\PUBLIC\MYDB.GDB

Comment: A commit retaining is not a full commit. Depending on the transaction isolation level used, transactions may not see the changes from commit retaining until it is really committed (when a connection is closed, the transaction is completed by the server). You might want to try a real commit instead, or change your isolation level.

Comment: I wrote about Firebird events, which might be helpful here: [Firebird Database Events and Message-oriented Middleware (part 1)](https://mikejustin.wordpress.com/2012/11/06/firebird-database-events-and-message-oriented-middleware/) [(part 2)](https://mikejustin.wordpress.com/2012/11/08/firebird-database-events-and-message-oriented-middleware-part-2/)

Comment: Which [transaction isolation level](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/isql-transactions.html) do the clients use? `Read Committed` or a different one?

Comment: After reading http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/papers_presentations/html/paper-fbent-impacting.html it seems that Commit Retaining is a legacy (BDE) 'feature' to support desktop databases. With Firebird it seems unneccessary and dangreous as it can degrade performance.

Comment: Firebird is a more hands-on DB than what BDE provided. That being said it then allows for greater control. Spend time learning how transactions work and how to use them and you will later wonder how you ever  lived without them,

Comment: Doing a normal commit is from what I have experienced and from what I have read for many years the preferred way.

Comment: I also use the IBObjects library and do recommend it to anyone who is looking to use Firebird. It has a "If you came from BDE" option/post

Comment: I'm changing code to make normal commits so I think it'll work.   I'm working on something I haven't written, doing a favour to a friend, so I was just trying to find a quick fix to a problem made by someone else :(

Answer (score 1):

It is normal that the information will only be shown after reopening the dataset on the other computers.

The server will not *automagically* send the changes to the other clients.

So the behaviour you noticed is by design, not a bug.

Comment: Maybe you missunderstand my post... I'm not expecting that magically all dataset will be updated... but if I insert a record on PC1 and make a query on PC2 I'm expecting that record to be present in the result. I think my problem is connected to what @Mark Rotteveel said in his comment :(

Comment: @Bux Which [transaction isolation level](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/isql-transactions.html) do the clients use?

Answer (score 1):

To refresh data on other clients, You might use built into firebird DB 
Events. More information in Firebird documentation:
[firebirdsql.org](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/papers_presentations/Power_Firebird_events.pdf)

Additionally, depending on delphi version, You would use for example so called "database alerts" being part of FireDAC :
[Embarcadero Alerts wiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Database_Alerts_%28FireDAC%29)

If You use older versions / don't have CS Addon, please refer to specific documentation, according to tools You use for DB connectivity.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder whether this is something to do with using the IBX components with Firebird, because I don't get the same result with a DBXExpress app?

Below is the code & dfm of a minimalist DBX XE7 app that accesses a Firebird fdb.  Running two instances of this app and clicking the `AutoRefresh` button in one of them, changes/inserts made in the second instance show up in the first instance on the next `OnTimer` event, regardless of whether the `CommitRetaining` param of the `SqlConnection` is set to `True` or `False`.

Code:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    CDS1: TClientDataSet;
    DataSetProvider1: TDataSetProvider;
    SQLConnection1: TSQLConnection;
    SQLQuery1: TSQLQuery;
    DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    btnAutoRefresh: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    SQLMonitor1: TSQLMonitor;
    procedure btnAutoRefreshClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure CDS1AfterPost(DataSet: TDataSet);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure SQLMonitor1LogTrace(Sender: TObject; TraceInfo: TDBXTraceInfo);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.btnAutoRefreshClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := not Timer1.Enabled;
end;

procedure TForm1.CDS1AfterPost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  CDS1.ApplyUpdates(0);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CDS1.Open;
end;

procedure TForm1.SQLMonitor1LogTrace(Sender: TObject; TraceInfo: TDBXTraceInfo);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(TraceInfo.Message);
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SqlQuery1.Close;
  CDS1.Close;
  CDS1.Open;
end;

end.
```

DFM:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 258
  Top = 150
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 344
  ClientWidth = 594
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object DBGrid1: TDBGrid
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 594
    Height = 120
    Align = alTop
    DataSource = DataSource1
    TabOrder = 0
    TitleFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    TitleFont.Color = clWindowText
    TitleFont.Height = -11
    TitleFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
    TitleFont.Style = []
    Columns = <
      item
        Expanded = False
        FieldName = 'ID'
        Visible = True
      end
      item
        Expanded = False
        FieldName = 'NAME'
        Width = 180
        Visible = True
      end
      item
        Expanded = False
        FieldName = 'AVALUE'
        Width = 200
        Visible = True
      end>
  end
  object DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator
    Left = 24
    Top = 136
    Width = 240
    Height = 25
    DataSource = DataSource1
    TabOrder = 1
  end
  object btnAutoRefresh: TButton
    Left = 312
    Top = 136
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'AutoRefresh'
    TabOrder = 2
    OnClick = btnAutoRefreshClick
  end
  object Memo1: TMemo
    Left = 0
    Top = 176
    Width = 594
    Height = 160
    Lines.Strings = (
      'Memo1')
    ScrollBars = ssBoth
    TabOrder = 3
  end
  object DataSource1: TDataSource
    DataSet = CDS1
    Left = 224
    Top = 64
  end
  object CDS1: TClientDataSet
    Active = True
    Aggregates = <>
    Params = <>
    ProviderName = 'DataSetProvider1'
    AfterPost = CDS1AfterPost
    Left = 216
    Top = 24
  end
  object DataSetProvider1: TDataSetProvider
    DataSet = SQLQuery1
    Left = 160
    Top = 24
  end
  object SQLConnection1: TSQLConnection
    ConnectionName = 'FBConnection'
    DriverName = 'Firebird'
    LoginPrompt = False
    Params.Strings = (
      'DriverName=Firebird'
      'Database=d:\delphi\firebird\databases\ma.fdb'
      'RoleName=RoleName'
      'User_Name=sysdba'
      'Password=masterkey'
      'ServerCharSet='
      'SQLDialect=3'
      'ErrorResourceFile='
      'LocaleCode=0000'
      'BlobSize=-1'
      'CommitRetain=False'
      'WaitOnLocks=True'
      'IsolationLevel=ReadCommitted'
      'Trim Char=False')
    Left = 24
    Top = 24
  end
  object SQLQuery1: TSQLQuery
    MaxBlobSize = -1
    Params = <>
    SQL.Strings = (
      'select * from table1')
    SQLConnection = SQLConnection1
    Left = 104
    Top = 24
  end
  object Timer1: TTimer
    Enabled = False
    Interval = 2000
    OnTimer = Timer1Timer
    Left = 328
    Top = 48
  end
  object SQLMonitor1: TSQLMonitor
    Active = True
    OnLogTrace = SQLMonitor1LogTrace
    SQLConnection = SQLConnection1
    Left = 288
    Top = 96
  end
end
```